# Make 2 charts using chart js

Tags: html, chart.js

So I want to try to make a website that includes charts. I used chart.js for it. Now i try to make two charts so i copied the one i make before and changed its variable but it doesn't shown up on my html page. What i want to ask is, is it possible to make 2 charts using chart.js and I did it the wrong way or i only can make one chart? Thank you.
By the way, here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Chart Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

        let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels:['Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Cambridge', 'New Bedford'],
                datasets:[{
                    label : 'Population',
                    data: [
                    617594,
                    181045,
                    153060,
                    106519,
                    105162,
                    95072
                    ],
                }]
            },
            options : {},
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        let myChart2 = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');

        let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart2, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels:['Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Cambridge', 'New Bedford'],
                datasets:[{
                    label : 'Population',
                    data: [
                    617594,
                    181045,
                    153060,
                    106519,
                    105162,
                    95072
                    ],
                }]
            },
            options : {},
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same variable name for both of the charts that is `massPopChart`. You just need to change the variable name to `massPopChart1` and `massPopChart2`.

Just check out the proper working here https://jsfiddle.net/4gdtujve/